# Resizable rows in ItemsControl, ListView, ListBox, or DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any possible way to have the rows be resizable on a `ItemsControl`, `ListView`, `ListBox`, or `DataGrid`?

The only way I can make what I want is like this:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <SomeControlGoesHere />
        <GridSplitter Height="5" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <SomeControlGoesHere />
        <GridSplitter Height="5" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <SomeControlGoesHere />
        <GridSplitter Height="5" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</UniformGrid>
```

This is an example with 3 sections that I can resize. I would like to make the number arbitrary and have data bound, and be able to specify a template.

I can't recreate this with any `ItemsControl` because the item container must be a `ContentControl`, which grid is not. If the grid is wrapped in anything, it doesn't behave like I need it to.

Is there a build in way with any of these controls to do this?

Is there another way to create resizable sections like this?

Worse comes to worse, is there a 3rd party control that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the best way to do this is to create the correct grid for this.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <SomeControl />
    <GridSplitter Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" />
    <SomeControl Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

So I created a custom control that inherits `Grid` that will allow me to bind items to it. This is not fully featured and has pretty much just the things I need; one being an `ItemTemplate`.

```
public class BindableGrid : Grid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "ItemsSource", typeof( IEnumerable ), typeof( BindableGrid ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( null, OnItemsSourceChanged ) );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "ItemTemplate", typeof( DataTemplate ), typeof( BindableGrid ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( null, OnItemTemplateChanged ) );

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue( ItemsSourceProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ItemsSourceProperty, value ); }
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue( ItemTemplateProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ItemTemplateProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static void OnItemsSourceChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        ( (BindableGrid)d ).OnItemsSourceChanged( (IEnumerable)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable)e.NewValue );
    }

    public void OnItemsSourceChanged( IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue )
    {
        INotifyCollectionChanged oldValueNotify;
        if( ( oldValueNotify = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged ) != null )
        {
            oldValueNotify.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }

        INotifyCollectionChanged newValueNotify;
        if( ( newValueNotify = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged ) != null )
        {
            newValueNotify.CollectionChanged += ItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    public static void OnItemTemplateChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        ( (BindableGrid)d ).OnItemTemplateChanged( (DataTemplate)e.OldValue, (DataTemplate)e.NewValue );
    }

    public void OnItemTemplateChanged( DataTemplate oldItemTemplate, DataTemplate newItemTemplate )
    {
    }

    private void ItemsSourceCollectionChanged( object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset )
        {
            RowDefinitions.Clear();
            Children.Clear();
        }
        else if( e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add )
        {
            AddItems( e.NewItems );
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( string.Format( "Action '{0}' is not valid.", e.Action ) );
        }
    }

    private void AddItems( IList items )
    {
        foreach( var item in items )
        {
            if( Children.Count > 0 )
            {
                RowDefinitions.Add( new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto } );
                var gridSplitter = new GridSplitter
                {
                    Height = 5,
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush( Color.FromArgb( 255, 0, 0, 0 ) ),
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                };
                SetRow( gridSplitter, Children.Count );
                Children.Add( gridSplitter );
            }

            RowDefinitions.Add( new RowDefinition
            {
                Height = new GridLength( 1, GridUnitType.Star ),
                MinHeight = 40,
            } );
            var contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
            contentPresenter.SetValue( ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateProperty, ItemTemplate );
            contentPresenter.Content = item;
            SetRow( contentPresenter, Children.Count );
            Children.Add( contentPresenter );
        }
    }
}
```